# Why does using LINQ change properties when used in if

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

when I use `someList.Where(t => t.isTrue = true)` nothing happens. But when I use code as given below,

```
 if(someList.Where(t => t.isTrue = true).Count() > 0) 
    return;
```

All items inside the list are set to true. Why this is happening?

Edit : I am not trying to assign or compare anything. I am curious about why this happens when used with `if`.

Comment: I think you need to look up basic operators in c# because = != ==

Comment: If only the compiler issued some sort of warning when you assign a  bool inside a comparison /s

Comment: Does my answer make it clear why this happens ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir  thanks. I think u r the only one who understood the question :D

Comment: @SAT I get that it's weird behavior at first, I've seen this issue a couple of times so I knew where the confusion was coming from :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because you use an assignment instead (`=`) of equality compare (`==`).

Also it only happens when you use `Count` because LINQ only evaluates the lambda expression when it has to get a value.

```
var q = someList.Where(t => t.isTrue = true); // Nothing will happen 
q.ToList() // would happen here 
if(q.Count() > 0 ) { .. } // Also here
```

To compare and not assign the value you should use:

```
var q = someList.Where(t => t.isTrue == true); 
var q = someList.Where(t => t.isTrue);  // Or simpler
```

The reason the compiler allows this is because assignment is an expression that has a value. For example :

```
int a = 10;
int b;
int c = (b = a) ; // (a=b) is of type int even though it also assigns a value, and b and c will have a value of 10
```

In your case, the assignment of a `bool` has type `bool`, which happens to be a valid return value for a lambda passed to `Where`

Answer (score 3):

All items inside the list are set to true when you use `=` and then evaluates the expression by using `Count()`.

As the isTrue is a boolean this would be enough to count the values which is true

```
if(someList.Where(t => t.isTrue).Count() > 0) 
    return;
```

As an alternative to checking if the count is higher than 0 you can use the Any method which already does just that

```
if(someList.Where(t => t.isTrue).Any())  // Any returns true if there are any elements in the collection
    return;
```

You can further simplify this with an overload of Any that takes the condition as a parameter, skiping the additional Where

```
if(someList.Any(t => t.isTrue))  // This overload takes a function that returns a boolean like Where does and returns true if there is at least 1 element that matches the condition
    return;
```

Comment: Where did he say he want to count things?

Comment: @MatJ When his code used `.Count()` in his question?